# ayuda para reparar mi proyecto Android despues de importar una dependencia

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-manifest

Estoy trabajando con firebase y al tratar de agregar el inicio de sesion con facebook importe la depencencia necesaria pero despues de sincronizar el proyecto basicamente todo se destruyo en la imagen se ve el estado actual del manifest[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ese no es el contenido del archivo manifest...

Comment: despues de trartar de agregar la dependencia quedo asi y muchos de los archivos quedaron asi tambien

Comment: ¿Estas diciendo que al agregar la dependencia te daño algunos archivos como el manifest?

Comment: Todo eso no es parte del manifest y no deberia estar ahi

Comment: ¿Tengo curiosidad por saber que dependencia agregaste en tu build.gradle antes de sincronizar y ver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Este es un caso similar a cuando en lugar de ver .xml en los layouts o el AndroidManifest.xml ves "código"; ahora aquí ves "código" en los en los layouts o el AndroidManifest.xml.

Generalmente esto se debe a desincronización de algunos archivos con respecto al tratar de construirse de acuerdo a  las dependencias definidas el archivo `build.gradle`, invalida caché en `Android Studio`:

`File` > `Invalidate Cache / Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]